# Branch or Fork a Conda Environment

Tags: conda

I would like to copy a conda environment under a different name.

I have a conda environment that I like.  I would like to create a new environment with a copy so that I can make some experimental edits.  In `git` parlance I'm looking for `branch` or `checkout -b`.

- Does such a `branch` or `fork` feature exist in conda?
- If not what is the best workaround today?

Answer (score 10):

the above (export|create) information still works, but is out of date now, `conda` now has a CLONE option:

```
conda create --clone <existing enviroment> -n <new environment>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a copy of the environment by using `conda env export > environment.yml` on all platforms and then activate that env with `conda env create -f environment.yml`. Make your desired changes and when you want to revert then activate your orginal environment.