# How to use Conda-installed Python module outside environment

Tags: python, conda, cupy, cusignal

I have downloaded `cusignal` with Conda using:

```
conda create -n rapids-22.02 -c rapidsai -c nvidia -c conda-forge \
    cusignal=22.02 python=3.8 cudatoolkit=11.2
```

I have many other libraries that I use in main terminal, i.e., without activating environment. However, I cannot access the `cusignal` module from there:

```
mark@linuxdesktop:~ python3
>>import cusignal
```

No library found.
But when I activate the environment that I have downloaded the cusignal library it doesn't give any error.

```
(rapids-22.02) mark@linuxdesktop:~ python3
>>import cusignal
```

To be able to use the `cusignal` properties in main system, is there any way to access that library without activating this environment?

Comment: To my knowledge, you have to either install you packages to the base environment or make a clone of the base environment and add the new packages to that environment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746749/branch-or-fork-a-conda-environment

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Generally, reconsider your workflow. While it may seem convenient to pile everything into a single monolithic environment, organizing your projects into distinct sets of software requirements is more sustainable and eases the transition to production.

Answer (score 1):

Not in any way that isn't a hack. The RAPIDS libraries rely on compiled packages that are managed through Conda, and trying to load the module outside of the context that provides those compiled libraries can lead to undefined behavior (e.g., missing symbol references).

### PYTHONPATH (not recommended)

Technically, if the Python version matches up through minor (e.g., both are 3.8), one could try including the environment's `site-packages` via the PYTHONPATH environment variable. That is, something like,

```bash
mark@linuxdesktop:~ PYTHONPATH=/path/to/envs/rapids-22.02/lib/python3.8/site-packages python3
>> import cusignal
```

should at least find the package, but it might have an issue loading shared libraries.