# Combining conda env to normal global env M1 mac - python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, package, conda

I have a problem with the kernel. I install cv2 by conda, and the kernel is in this directory: Caskroom/..../python. But if I run by this kernel, it will lack some packages, for ex: numpy, patplotlib, ....

These packages are in the **global env**. I want to merge them into 1. Something likes running global env and it includes the packages I've installed by conda.

[image: Change kernel]

Comment: Possibly related (though my real answer is "don't"): https://stackoverflow.com/q/71573113/570918

Comment: You can activate the conda environment and *still* use pip on that environment. That's how my current setup works due to some libraries being only available through miniforge in m1.  Just activate the conda environment and use pip for stuff that doesn't exist in conda.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should not be possible. I can only reinstall these necessary packages in the new environment.